# Saved game not restoring anymore in No Man's Sky

Tags: pc, windows-7, no-mans-sky

I've been playing NMS for the past 4-5 days now. I had collected ~1M units, learned over 120 alien words, met >30 aliens on 4 star systems and so on, so forth. I last saved my game (successfully) yesterday morning (2 AM). Today (IST 9 PM) when I tried to start the game again, it started from the beginning. I immediately went to the options page, and noticed that it does hold the last saved checkpoint from yesterday.

[image]

But, when trying to reload those saved games, nothing happens. I am stuck at the very beginning of the game again. I ran a system `chkdsk` as well, to if the files got corrupt. But there is nothing wrong with the machine itself.

Is it a bug in the game? Can the saved game be restored? Right now, I force quit the application from task manager, just to avoid overwriting the saved game data.

Comment: You should first backup the save file (Coping them the your Eg: Desktop)